# pivot table - date data rows to columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-columns

i have a SQL table that stores attendance ( punch in and punch out) of employees, i am currently working to get the total working hour of every day stored in the table(the total days is about 22 to 30 days maximum)..
the data stored is like below:

```
ID  date        time        Status
1   01/08/2015  08:00 AM    IN
1   01/08/2015  01:00 PM    OUT
1   01/08/2015  02:30 PM    IN
1   01/08/2015  07:30 PM    OUT
1   02/08/2015  11:00 AM    IN
1   02/08/2015  06:00 PM    OUT
1   02/08/2015  09:30 PM    IN
1   03/08/2015  02:30 AM    OUT
1   03/08/2015  08:00 AM    IN
1   03/08/2015  06:00 PM    OUT
1   04/08/2015  08:00 AM    IN
1   04/08/2015  06:00 PM    OUT
```

now i want the data to be like below:

```
ID  01/08/2015  02/08/2015  03/08/2015  04/08/2015  total
1       10          12          10          10      42
2       9           10          10          11      40
```

i have read a lot of article about the pivot table but all of them use a specific number of columns inside it, so how to solve it dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX)

select  @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME( cast(CONVERT( VARCHAR(20), Edate,103 ) as varchar(10)))   
                    from   
                    (  
                     select a1.Edate from (
                        SELECT DISTINCT   Edate 
                        from InOut  
                      )a1

                    ) t  

            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')   
        ,1,1,'')  

    EXEC( ' SELECT Id,' + @cols + '    
            from   
            (  
              select Id,
                 Edate ,  
                status
              from  
              (  
                select convert(varchar(20), Edate,103)Edate, Id,status
                from InOut
              ) src  
            ) x  
            pivot   
            (  
                count(status)  
                for Edate in (' + @cols + ')  
            ) p where 1=1 ')
```

Comment: hello pradip, this is a feasible solution, and it gives the total days allocated in attendance table as columns, but it doesn't return the total working hour by day, it gives the count of the record of each day :P anw thank you for answering me